# Styles for individual table cells in Writer

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

The question is pretty short, but important for me. In LO 5.3 there is a new feature called "table styles". But as I understand, it adds styling to the overall table, while I want to add styles to individual cells.

In other words, I want styles like "Green Cell", "Red Cell", and so on. Like this:

[image]

Is there way for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to select an individual cell rather than the entire table.

1. Start with a blank Writer document and `Table -> Insert Table`, Insert, Close.
2. Select cell A1 by clicking in it and dragging the mouse somewhat to the right.  Be careful not to select the whole row.
   [image: select cell A1]
3. In the Table Styles list, double-click the `Red` style.
4. Do the same for cell A2, using the `Green` style.

The result:

[image]